# TypeError: Invalid Invocation in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am modifying chrome proxy setting in a Native Messaging callback in background.js. I get "Error in event handler: TypeError: Invalid Invocation" when modifying proxy setting. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
function applyNetwork(Data) {
    var config = {
      mode: "fixed_servers",
      rules: {
        singleProxy: {
          scheme: "socks5",
          host: Data.Host,
          port: parseInt(Data.Port)
        }
      }
    };
    chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {}); // error here
}
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {

        applyNetwork(msg.Reply);
        ...
});
```

Comment: Inspect the values you pass to the API i.e. your msg.Reply. Maybe it has an invalid port.

Comment: Exactly, Port is string, not number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [woxxom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom), it turns out to be invalid port.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33776866)